# Irreducible polynomials .

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Prove whether the polynomials $f=X^2+ X +3$ and $g=X^3+X+1$ are irreducible in the field  $\Bbb Z_5$

The fact that the polynomials are given in pairs made me think that I should find their $\gcd$ and if that equals $1$ then they are irreducible, but I think there is more to if as they could still be factorised even if their gcd is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. This is easier than you think. If a quadratic or cubic is  reducible it has a root. That's an easy short check.

Comment: But if it has a root in the given field then it can be factorised so therefore it is not irreducible

Comment: @MorenaDragomir True: if a polynomial has a root you can factor it. The converse is true only for polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$. For those, checking irreducibility is equivalent to checking for roots.

Answer (score 0):

Since both of them have degree smaller than $4$ they are irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$ if and only if has no root in $\mathbb Z_5$. It turns out that the first polynomial is reducible (it is equal to $(X-1)(X-3)$), whereas the second one is irreducible.

Comment: ??? Oh, because $-4=1$ today...